# How to use placeholderChar in text-mask for Angular

Tags: angular, text-mask

I'm using text-mask in an Angular 7 project. I can't get placeholderChar to change from the default underscore.

```
  <input
    id="1"
    name="phone"
    placeholderChar="/u2000"
    [(ngModel)]="myModel"
    [textMask]="{mask: mask}"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
  />
```

In the app component

```
 constructor() {
this.mask = ['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', 
/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]
this.myModel = ''
this.modelWithValue = '5554441234'
this.formControlInput.setValue('5555551234')
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try putting mask = ['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', 
/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/] outside of the constructor.

Comment: I tried putting mask in ngOnInit without result

Comment: At their documentation, they declared it as (public) variable right after the class. In your cause would be right above the constructor. Documentation: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2#readme
If you make a stackblitz, we might be able to help you better.